# Cannot Access Left Joined Entity In LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql

I'm performing a left join in LINQ and I'm running into a problem. My problem is that I'm doing a comparison on two tables in my where clause, but I can't actually access the 'cat' table. How do I go about accessing the table in my left join?

```
var query = from apple in Apple
            join ball in Ball on apple.Id equals ball.AppleId
            join cat in Cat on ball.Id equals cat.BallId into leftJoin
            join dog in Dog on ball.Id equals dog.BallId
            where apple.Id == 5

            // At this point cat is not accessable. Cannot resolve symbol "cat".
            where dog.CatName == cat.Name

            from cat in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
               // select stuff here...
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but try this:

```
var query = from apple in Apple
            join ball in Ball on apple.Id equals ball.AppleId
            join cat in Cat on ball.Id equals cat.BallId into leftJoin
            from cat in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join dog in Dog on ball.Id equals dog.BallId
            where apple.Id == 5
            where dog.CatName == cat.Name
            select new
            {
               // select stuff here...
            };
```

Of course, if you set up your navigation properties appropriately this would look a bit like this:

```
var query = from apple in Apple
            from ball in apple.Balls
            from cat in ball.Cats.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from dog in ball.Dogs
            where apple.Id == 5
            where dog.CatName == cat.Name
            select new
            {
               // select stuff here...
            };
```

Comment: That worked. I needed the DefaultIfEmpty() method before the where clauses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have selected multiple cats into a LeftJoin... this makes it an IEnumerable so there is no single cat so the query doesn't exactly make sense... do you want to check if dog matches any of the cats that are joined?

I've renamed your `leftJoin` to be `catsForThisBall` to make it clearer.

```
var query = from apple in Apple
            join ball in Ball on apple.Id equals ball.AppleId
            join cat in Cat on ball.Id equals cat.BallId into catsForThisBall
            join dog in Dog on ball.Id equals dog.BallId
            where apple.Id == 5

            // catsForThisBall is IEnumerable<Cat>... cat doesn't exist.
            where catsForThisBall.Any(c => c.name == dog.name)

            select new
            {
               // select stuff here...
            };
```